# TypeDoc and modules

Tags: angular, typescript, typedoc

I'm trying to generate documentation for my TypeScript project with TypeDoc. The generation works, except for that I can't find out how to organise my classes into modules and have TypeDoc display them as such.

Currently my classes are just organized by directories, but TypeDoc doesn't seem to recognize that (everything is *Global*). I think there should be another way to define the modules, but I cannot find how.

Does anyone have experience with this? Thanks!

This is what I currently have:

[image]

This is what I'm trying to get:

[image]

Comment: Are you not creating namespaces for your TypeScript modules using `module myApp.myModule { [...] }`?

Comment: This is something I tried, it does show modules in the doc when i do that but it breaks my imports and I cannot get them to work that way.

Comment: Hmm, I've never tried it without using TypeScript modules so I don't know if there is a way to make it work how you want. Have you tried `--mode file`? Or play around with some of the other TypeDoc options.

Comment: I am currently using `--mode file`. I would like to organize my project in TypeScript modules, but it breaks the imports and i can't figure out how to get them to work like that...

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin which does the trick for me.
[typedoc-external-module-name](https://github.com/christopherthielen/typedoc-plugin-external-module-name)
You can organize the files in kind of "logical" modules.

Comment: I was looking for the a solution to the same problem and this was the answer for me. BTW, this plugin is listed in the [TypeDoc documentation](https://typedoc.org/guides/plugins).